# PHP Array Issues

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

I am building a simple cart for a friend and using an array in session to store it.

To add an item to the cart I have this code

```
$next_item = sizeof($_SESSION['cart']) +1;
$_SESSION['cart'][$next_item] = array(item => $product_id, option => $option, qty => 1);
```

What I'm struggling with how to update an item's quantity in this array should someone add another of the same item or update the cart. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: you simply may write `$_SESSION['cart'][]` and leave out the $nextItem tmp var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

    if ($_SESSION['cart'][$key]['item'] == $product_id) {

        $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty'] += $qty_to_add;
    }
}
```

I would change the structure of your array.

Instead of

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'item' => 1,
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1),
    2 => array(
        'item' => 2,
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1),
    3 => array(
        'item' => 3,
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1)
);
```

Use

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1),
    2 => array(
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1),
    3 => array(
        'option' => 1,
        'qty' => 1)
);
```

Where the key is the product id.  It will make referencing the items easier and you can update the quantity in one line

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty'] += $qty_to_add;
```

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important you can store your products in an associative array.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
    // set qty of $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] + 1
} else {
    // create $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] with qty of 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to calculate the array size:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(...);
```

Second, I would use `$product_id` as array key. That ways, searches are straightforward:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]) ){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty']++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = array(
        'option' => $option,
        'qty' => 1,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that you've chosen a good structure for it. How about indexing upon the $product_id instead? That way, you'll always know if you already have a specific item in your cart:

```
<?php
     if( isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]) ) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty'] += $new_qty;
     } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = array(item => $product_id, option => $option, qty => 1);
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: D'oh, a little bit slower than the rest. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To add something to the cart, simply use this (assuming product ids are unique):

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = array('item' => $product_id, 'option' => $option, 'qty' => 1);
```

To set the quantity for any given product id to 5, use this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty'] = 5;
```

To increase the qty of a product by 3, use this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty'] += 3;
```